# How to prevent function from trigger during a certain time (while animating)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, animation, queue

I have a UI that has a box zooming in and out on click. It is animated, and when the box is closed, another animation is supposed to run. Both events are handled with the same function and some conditions.

The bug is that when the box is open, I click it, and then click it again before the zoom out animation is finished, is is zoomed back in but the animation that is supposed to run only when it is zoomed out, is triggered.

- correct behavior: http://cl.ly/2M0a3T3e2V0g
- double-click buggy behavior: http://cl.ly/2l0E3x3L0h19

How do I make sure the after-zoom-out animation can be only triggered when the zoom out is complete? Here is the code (it is angular but it doesn't matter much here...):

```
animating = false; // I tried to use a flag, but it did not work

scope.toggleContextSlider = function() { // The click function
  if (scope.sliderClosed) { // The "avatar" is the "box"
    openSlider(scope.animtionDuration, scope.hearingContextAvatar); // The "avatar" is the "box"
  } else {
    closeSlider(scope.animtionDuration, scope.hearingContextAvatar);
  }
  scope.sliderClosed = !scope.sliderClosed;
}
```

The animation functions:

```
function openSlider(animtionDuration, hearingContextAvatar) {
  // Animating stuff

  if (hearingContextAvatar && !animating) {
    closeStuff(animtionDuration, hearingContextAvatar)
  }
}

function closeSlider(animtionDuration, hearingContextAvatar) {
  // Animating stuff

  if (hearingContextAvatar && !animating) {
    openStuff(animtionDuration, hearingContextAvatar)
  }
}

function openStuff(animtionDuration, currentAvatar) { // This is the functions that is triggered with the double click
  animating = true;
  setTimeout(function(){
    // Animating stuff
    animating = false;
  }, animtionDuration);
}

function closeStuff(animtionDuration, currentAvatar) {
  animating = true;
  currentAvatar.removeClass('open')
  setTimeout(function(){
    // Animating stuff
    animating = false;
  }, animtionDuration);
}
```

Comment: The openStuff() and closeStuff() functions are never called, so your boolean flag will never change its value from false.

Comment: @HankScorpio They are, I updated the names.

Comment: @ilyo Did you find what you want in my solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here you want to trigger some event according to another.
To do this, you can use **promise** with **$q**.

You will be able to use the promises power, and handle easily your event by resolving your promises.

The idea is to use two flags for example, which will tell us if the slider is open or not.

I created some animation function to show you how to deal with it. Here, i simulate an event with `for loop` and `$timeout` function.

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, $q, $timeout) {

  $scope.slide = true;

  var closeResolved = true;

  var openResolved = false;

  $scope.show = false;

  $scope.processing = [];

  $scope.closing = [];

  $scope.toggle = function() {
    if ($scope.slide && closeResolved){
      event('open processing').then(function(data){
        $scope.show = data;
        //openResolved set to true
        openResolved = data;
        //closeResolved set to false
        closeResolved = !data;
      });

      $scope.slide = !$scope.slide;

    } else if (!$scope.slide && openResolved) {
      event('close processing').then(function(data){
        $scope.show = !data;
        //closeResolved set to true
        closeResolved = data;
        //openResolved set to false
        openResolved = !data;
      });

      $scope.slide = !$scope.slide;
    }

  }

  function event(processing){
    //Return promise, and resolve when loop is over
    return $q(function(resolve){
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        (function(i){
          $timeout(function(){
            //Update info processing array
            $scope.processing.push(processing);
            if (i == 2)
              resolve(true);
          }, 500 * i);
        })(i);
      }
    });
  }


}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

    <button type="button" name="button" ng-click='toggle()'>Toggle</button>

    <h3 ng-if="show" style="color:green">OPEN</h3>
    <h3 ng-if="!show" style="color:red">CLOSE</h3>

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in processing track by $index">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>

 </body>
```

With this example, you can see that if you spam the toogle button, it will not raise multiple event. If you to start **close** event during an open event, it will wait until the event **open** is completed.

You can see [**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DJ9fb3WbtujXQbAhjZuA?p=preview)